# Trouble with python while loop

Tags: python

I'm sorry if this is a ridiculous question but I'm just learning python and I can't figure this out. :)

My program is supposed to print the capital of any state that the user inputs. Sometimes it will work ten times in a row, other times it will work three times in a row, and then it will just stop after you type in a state. If I restart it and type in the state that it stopped on it will work just fine....for a random number of times and then it will stop again. What am I doing wrong? Also is my code awful? I had no idea what sort of code to use for this so I just kind of tossed in whatever I could make work.

```
    x = str(raw_input('Please enter a sate: ' ))
    while x == 'Alabama':
        print 'Montgomery is the capital of', x
        x = str(raw_input('Please enter a state: '))
    while x ==  'Alaska':
        print 'Juneau is the capital of', x
        x = str(raw_input('Please enter a state: '))                  
    while x == 'Arizona':
        print 'Phoenix is the capital of', x
        x = str(raw_input('Please enter a state: ' ))
    while x == 'Arkansas':
        print 'Little Rock is the capital of', x
        x = str(raw_input('Please enter a state: '))'
```

Comment: Someone was trying to help with formatting of your code. You should either let them, or do it yourself so that the code is actually readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You mean to use multiple `if` statements within one big `while` loop, rather than multiple `while` loops. In this code, once you're past one while loop, you never come back to it. This code will work *only* as long as you are giving it state names in alphabetical order.
2. *Don't do it this way!* There is a *much* better way to do it using python [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

   ```
   capitals = {"Alabama": "Montgomery", "Alaska": "Juneau", "Arizona": "Phoenix", "Arkansas": "Little Rock"}
   while True:
       x = str(raw_input('Please enter a state: ' ))
       if x in capitals:
           print capitals[x], "is the capital of", x
   ```

Otherwise, you'll end up having 50 pairs of almost identical lines if you want to cover all 50 states.

Comment: Thank you so much!! We haven't covered dictionaries yet, I should have waited until then to try to do this lol

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand the `while` loop.  Basically,

```
while condition:
    dostuff()
```

does stuff while the condition is true.  As soon as the condition is false, you move on.  I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
x=True
while x 
   x=raw_input('please enter a state'):
   if x == 'Alabama':
      ...
   elif x == 'Alaska':
      ...
```

This will loop forever until the user just hits enter (`bool('')` is `False` in python)

However, a much better way to do it would be to use a dictionary:

```
state_capitals={'Alabama':'Montgomery', 'Alaska':'Juneau'}
x=True
while x 
   x=raw_input('please enter a state'):
   print '{0} is the capital of {1}'.format(state_capitals[x],x)
```

with this way, it will raise a `KeyError` when a bad capital is given (which you could catch using a `try` block if you wanted to).

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty it is way worse then *awful*. However, you are most likely a beginner and thus such things happen.

For this task you should use a `dict` that contains the country=>capital mappings and read the country name *once*:

```
capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
            'Alaska': 'Juneau',
          ...}
state = raw_input('Please enter a state: ')
if(state in capitals):
    print '{0} is the capital of {1}'.format(capitals[state], state)
else:
    print 'Sorry, but I do not recognize {0}'.format(state)
```

If you want to use a `while` loop so the user can enter multiple states, you can wrap the whole code in a `while True:` block and use `if not state: break` right after the `raw_input` line to break the loop if the user does not enter anything.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I am totally a beginner lol